Would Rabbinic Jews during the second temple have been allowed to marry Sadducees?
My understanding is that the Sadducees did not believe in resurrection of the dead and disagreed or interpreted the oral tradition very differently than the Pharisees and Rabbinic Jews in the times of Bayit Sheni. At the end of tractate Kiddushin it lists different groups of Jews and indicates which groups are allowed to marry each other. There is no indication there that Sadducees are a group that is forbidden to marry.
My question is, are there any sources in the mishna, midrash halacha, tosefta or talmudim which would indicate whether or not Rabbinic Jews would have been permitted to marry Sadducees (and vice versa) or not?

The Mishnah says: "If the Sadducee women abandoned the customs of their ancestors in order to follow in the ways of the Jewish people their status is like that of a Jewish woman."  [Niddah 33b]  I conclude that Sadducee women could marry Pharisees if they agreed to follow Rabbinic Judaism.  (The Gemara adds that many Sadducee women married to Sadducees followed the rabbis anyway.)

The Saducees only existed for a short amount of time, from the middle of the Hasmonean period to the destruction of the temple. They wouldn't be relevant in the time of the Gemara but you might find references to min(im) - heretical sects of Judaism.
The Karites are a sect that is still around today. They also held views different from normative Jews. Like the Saducees, they also deny aspects/authority of the oral law. They claim a connection to the Saducees, though they were separated by about 1000 years.
There is a presumption that they are all Mamzerim (bastards) because over the years, more and more people will be descended from remarried divorcees who did not divorce in a rabbinically approved manner. However, in 1972 R' Ovadia Yosef ruled you can marry a Karite who accepts rabbinic law, which would imply the bastardy really isn't a problem.(Perhaps he held that rabbinic bastardy is only a fence and the Karites aren't held to be d'orita bastards).
In contrast to the Karites, the Saducees wouldn't have enough time to propagate bastards and, since many of them lived and died before the Mishna Rabbis, rabbinic bastardy might not have been codified yet. If you wanted to marry a Saducee, asking around on an individual level would probably suffice to rule out an improper divorce.
